# regular expression matching string in scala

Tags: regex, scala

I have a string like this

```
result: String = /home/administrator/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-    SNAPPSHOT/com/a/infra/UserAccountDetailsMetaData$.class
/home/administrator/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-    SNAPSHOT/com/a/infra/UserAccountDetailsMetaData.class
/home/administrator/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT/com/a/infra/UserAccountMetaData$.class
/home/administrator/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT/com/a/infra/UserAccountMetaData.class
/home/administrator/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT/com/a/infra/UserOverridenFunctionMetaDataMetaData$.class
/home/administrator/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT/com/a/infra/UserOverridenFunctionMetaDataMetaData.class
/home/administrator/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT/com/a/infra/UserOverridenPermissionMetaData$.class
/home/administrator/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT/com/a/infra/UserOverridenPermissionMetaData.class
/home/administrator/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT/com/a/infra/UserRoleMetaData$.class
 /home/administrator/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT/com/a/infra/UserRoleMetaData.class
/home/administrator/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV- SNAPSHOT/com/a/infra/VendorAddressMetaData$.class
/home/administrator/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT/com/a/infra/VendorAddressMetaData.class
 /home/administrator/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT/com/reactore/infra/VendorContactMetaData$.class
/home/administrator/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT/com/reactore/infra/VendorContactMetaData.class
  /home/administrator/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT/com/reactore/infra/VendorMetaData$.class
  /home/administrator/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT/com/a/infra/VendorMetaData.class
  /home/administrator/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT/com/a/infra/WeekMetaData$.class
  /home/administrator/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT/com/a/infra/WeekMetaData.class
 /home/administrator/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT/com/a/infra/WorkflowMetadataMetaData$.class
 /home/administrator/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT/com/a/infra/WorkflowMetadataMetaData.class
/home/administrator/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT/com/a/infra/WorkflowNotificationMetaData$.class
/home/administrator/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT/com/a/infra/WorkflowNotificationMetaData.class
 /home/a/usr/share/common-api/lib/com.supai.common-api-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
 /home/a/usr/share/common-api/lib/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT.jar
/home/common/usr/share/common-api/lib/com.supai.common-api-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
/home/raghav/usr/share/common-api/lib/com.supai.common-api-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
/home/sysadmin/usr/share/common-api/lib/com.supai.common-api-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
/home/tmp/usr/share/common-api/lib/com.supai.common-api-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
/home/usr/share/common-api/lib/com.supai.common-api-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
/home/usr/share/common-api/lib/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT.jar
/usr/share/common-api/lib/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT.jar
regex: scala.util.matching.Regex = (\\/([u|s|r])\\/([s|h|a|r|e]))
x: scala.util.matching.Regex.MatchIterator = empty iterator`
```

and out of this how can I get only this part `/usr/share/common-api/lib/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT.jar`and this part can be anywhere in the string, how can I achieve this, I tried using regular expression in Scala but don't know how to use forward slashes, so anybody plz explain how to do this in scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your search criteria? Your pattern seems to be wrong.
In your rexexp, I see `u|s|r` which means to search for either `u`, **or** `s` **or** `r` . See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) for more information

> how can I get only this part
>   /usr/share/common-api/lib/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT.jarand
>   this part can be anywhere in the string

If you are looking for a path, see the below example:

```
scala> val input = """/home/common/usr/share/common-api/lib/com.supai.common-api-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
     |     /home/raghav/usr/share/common-api/lib/com.supai.common-api-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
     |     /home/sysadmin/usr/share/common-api/lib/com.supai.common-api-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
     |     /home/tmp/usr/share/common-api/lib/com.supai.common-api-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
     |     /home/usr/share/common-api/lib/com.supai.common-api-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
     |     /home/usr/share/common-api/lib/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT.jar
     |     /usr/share/common-api/lib/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT.jar"""
input: String =
/home/common/usr/share/common-api/lib/com.supai.common-api-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
    /home/raghav/usr/share/common-api/lib/com.supai.common-api-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
    /home/sysadmin/usr/share/common-api/lib/com.supai.common-api-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
    /home/tmp/usr/share/common-api/lib/com.supai.common-api-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
    /home/usr/share/common-api/lib/com.supai.common-api-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
    /home/usr/share/common-api/lib/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT.jar
    /usr/share/common-api/lib/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT.jar

scala> val myRegExp = "/usr/share/common-api/lib/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT.jar".r
myRegExp: scala.util.matching.Regex = /usr/share/common-api/lib/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT.jar

scala> val myRegExp2 = "helloWorld.jar".r
myRegExp2: scala.util.matching.Regex = helloWorld.jar
scala> (myRegExp findAllIn input) foreach( println)
/usr/share/common-api/lib/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT.jar
/usr/share/common-api/lib/com.supai.common-api-1.8.5-DEV-SNAPSHOT.jar

scala> (myRegExp2 findAllIn input) foreach( println)

scala>
```